# jQuery: how to remove class from nearest elements in parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have next HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="btn active">One</span>
            <span class="btn">Two</span>
            <span class="btn">Three</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="btn">One</span>
            <span class="btn active">Two</span>
            <span class="btn">Three</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I try to add class `active` to the current clicked element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn").click(function() {
        $(".btn").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

it works, but removes `active` class from all other spans.

How to remove `active` class only from the nearest elements, for example only inside the parent `td`?

Answer (score 2):

You can make sure you are removing the class only from the children of the parent element of the clicked span.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn").click(function() {
        $(this.parentElement.childNodes).removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To do what you require you can use the `this` keyword in the event handler to reference the element which raised the event. From there you can use jQuery's DOM traversal methods, in this case `siblings()`, to find the related elements and change their classes.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings('span').removeClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="btn active">One</span>
      <span class="btn">Two</span>
      <span class="btn">Three</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="btn">One</span>
      <span class="btn active">Two</span>
      <span class="btn">Three</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.btn').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="btn active">One</span>
      <span class="btn">Two</span>
      <span class="btn">Three</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="btn">One</span>
      <span class="btn active">Two</span>
      <span class="btn">Three</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```